# ASP.NET MVC 4 With knockout

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

i am using Asp.net MVC .I need to validate  all the input fields on form submit  using Knockout.

My View is here below. How to apply Validation using knockout. I don't want to apply Observable for each and every field.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U74SM.png)      [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohVxb.png)

```
<div data-bind="with:Student">
    <form method="post" action="/Home/Save">
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" name="Name" data-bind="value:Name" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAge" name="Age" data-bind="value:Age" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>DOB</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtDOB" name="Age" data-bind="value:DOB" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Street Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtStreetName" name="StreetName" data-bind="value:StreetName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="Address" data-bind="value:Address" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="City" data-bind="value:City" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtState" name="State" data-bind="value:State" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCountry" name="Country" data-bind="value:Country" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="Email" data-bind="value:Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtMobile" name="Mobile" data-bind="value:Mobile" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please (a) share your code as text instead of an image, and (b) show us what you've already tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @user3297291 Please find the code. I want to validate all the fields. And mostly i need in generic type ,so that i can implement for other pages

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, why don't you pull all this data from a model?

If you create a model, you can add validation right into the declaration of the fields:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourProject.Models {

    public class ModelName {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Age")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your DOB")]
        public string DOB { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Street Name")]
        public string STreetName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your State")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Email")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Mobile")]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you do some research you can find other ways you can validate data this way, like restricting to a certain length or certain kinds of characters. I don't really know what else you want in terms of validation, but this would certainly help, and I'm also assuming you have the base knowledge of MVC to pass a model to your view through your controller.

Comment: i know this Model Validation already,but i don't want to apply at C# End(data Annotation). I need to apply everything at scripting side(Client). Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) knockout validation library on github. Easy to use. Simply extend the observable you want to add validation to. You can also use HTML5 Validation Attributes in your view.

Comment: I have already seen this and applied too. I want this to this Extend method to be Generic type in Scripting side. Since i am using lot of Forms, if it is generic type validation it will be easy .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "generic". There is always going to be work involved in applying validation whether on the client or server. My recommendation is to use html attributes as demonstrated in the knockout validation documentation. This requires hardly any work on your part e.g 
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myProp" required /> 
<input type="number" data-bind="value: myProp" min="2" />

Something else to look at is the [knockout validation rule engine](https://github.com/ctoestreich/knockout-validation-rule-engine) library. Disclaimer: I've never used it myself :)